# What is the purpose of the 'metal' folder in a programming language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at Rails ActionController and am curious what the meaning behind the 'metal' folder is? Why name it 'metal'?

I also know Ember has an Ember-Metal module and i'm sure there are other programming use cases for it.

Is there a convention for naming 'metal'?

`actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/conditional_get.rb`

Comment: The canonical use-case example is a poller/health check endpoint that does essentially nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this article](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2008/12/17/introducing-rails-metal/) written by David Heinemeier Hansson

> Think of Rails Metal as a subset of middleware intended for
>   application-specific end points that need the extra speed (“write to
>   the metal”, hence the name).